# React-Native App access Firestore with Google gmail authenication

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have read Firebase docs, a lot of articles and stackoverflow posting without finding anything that talks about using Firebase Gmail based authentication to access a Firebase firestore collection.  Most articles have the firestore in test mode with open access or they are using Firebase's email/password Auth and a collection in firestore.  The Firebase's email/password Auth with email/password shows the following rule.

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.uid = !null.
```

This doesn't work, because I can't pass the uid (Gmail doesn't have it) when requesting the data from firestore.

Ideally, I would like to use the JWT returned from the Firebase Gmail authentication and sent it to Firestore request.  Again, I couldn't find a single example of Firebase firestore using a token.

If there is an article, docs or just experience, please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to manually "send" a JWT with a query.  When using the Firebase client SDKs in your app, authentication tokens can only be sent automatically along with a query if you're also using Firebase Authentication to authenticate the user.  If you're not using Firebase Auth, then there will be no token that identifies the user, which means you can't use `request.auth` at all in your security rules.

Firebase Authentication does [support Google as an authentication provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin), so you should be able to use the two together in your app if you want write effective security rules.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Just to confirm, if I'm using anything other than Firebase Auth email/password for authentication, such as Google gmail, it will not work.  Would a Firebase Cloud Function taking JWT from the client, validating and then querying the firestore work?

Comment: You can use any Authentication provider supported by Firebase Authentication, or even your own custom auth provider.  But you have to be using Firebase Authentication to manage the token and sign-in.  You can't use Google auth alone because it doesn't know how to inject any relevant information into the query managed by the database SDK.